# ffmpeg fails with "More than 1k frames duplicated" when merging with xfade

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

When I try to merge 8 or more video clips with the same codec (generated by ffmpeg in a previous step), I get a `More than 1000 frames duplicated` warning and the resulting output is not merged correctly. This doesn't happen with 7 video clips.

I tried removing the 8th clip to check if there is a problem with that clip, but it happens the same. Also reordering the clips with no success.

The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg -i scenes/step-000.mp4 -i scenes/step-001.mp4 -i scenes/step-002.mp4 -i scenes/step-003.mp4 -i scenes/step-004.mp4 -i scenes/step-005.mp4 -i scenes/step-008.mp4 -i scenes/step-009.mp4 -filter_complex_script temp/2021-03-17-14-51-13-6.txt  -y -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

The content of the `filter_complex_script` is:

```
[0][1] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=2.48 [vtmp1]; [vtmp1][2] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=12.56 [vtmp2]; [vtmp2][3] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=100.58 [vtmp3]; [vtmp3][4] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=167.60 [vtmp4]; [vtmp4][5] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=222.62 [vtmp5]; [vtmp5][6] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=232.70 [vtmp6]; [vtmp6][7] xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=282.72 [video]; [0:a][1:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp1]; [atmp1][2:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp2]; [atmp2][3:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp3]; [atmp3][4:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp4]; [atmp4][5:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp5]; [atmp5][6:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [atmp6]; [atmp6][7:a] acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri [audio]
```

FFMPEG version 4.3.2-tessus

Comment: Need to see the **complete** log.

Comment: @llogan hi I have the same issue, the multiple xfade works well for 11 videos, but produces bad output for 12 videos.  Complete log is at https://pastebin.com/T6r6Vk8X, appreciate if you could advise.

Comment: @Richard Get the most recent "git master" version and try again: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: @llogan Thanks a lot, ffmpeg-4.4-amd64-static works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. [Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) the most recent version: preferably a build from "git master".